# How to get radio buttons (list items) to stay selected during postback

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, postback, autopostback

Basically I have a RadioButtonList that is  in an UpdatePanel, which is inside of another UpdatePanel. Once I select an item in this list it immediately unselect itself, of course triggered by postback.  Now, nothing in my codebehind anywhere is changing the selected property of the RadioList. Now, I assumed with viewstatemode= enabled, the selected index would be preserved between postbacks. But what happens when The item is selected, it immediately becomes unselected.

My inner(nested) UpdatePanel code looks like this.

```
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="OptionsUpdater" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled"> 
     <ContentTemplate>
               <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="rightside" CssClass="column4 row2">
                        <%--Options Panel--%>
                        <div id="OptionsPanel">
                            <div style="padding: 2px; border-color: black; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; background-color: white; position: relative; top: -45px; left: -40px; border-radius: 8px;">
                                <p class="bluegradientBG3 massheader"
                                    style="margin-left: -5px; min-width: 305px; font-size: 1.5em; border-radius: 14px; font-family: Arial; text-align: center">
                                    Options
                                </p>
                                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="OptionsRadioList" runat="server"
                                    Height="120px" Width="269px"
                                    AutoPostBack="true"
                                    CellPadding="9"
                                    CellSpacing="2"
                                    ViewStateMode="Enabled"
                                    >
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="update">Update Existing Parts</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="add">Add New Parts</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="delete">Mass Delete</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="OptionsCheckList" runat="server" Height="100px" Width="269px"
                                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="OptionsCheckList_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="NTDs">Update NTDs Only</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="addpart">Add Part If None Assigned</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="changelocations">Change N/A Locations To Selected</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:CheckBoxList>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </ContentTemplate>
              </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And the outer UpdatePanel way up in the code looks like this:

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="OverallUpdater" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
     <ContentTemplate>

          //content omitted for brevity
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="viewapps" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="UpdateButton" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="FilterButton" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="OptionsRadioList" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" /> 
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

In PostBack, are you setting the data source of the RadioButtonList?  If so, that's what's resetting it.

If you want to load the datasource for the RBL just the first time the page loads for a user, put it inside a conditional like this:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    // Load your RBL with your data
}
```

Comment: There is no datasource for it.

Comment: Why is OptionsRadioList.SelectedIndexChanged an AsyncPostBackTrigger when you don't have a method in code-behind handling the event?

Comment: It wasn't originally, I was getting desperate and trying anything and everything to try and get it to work.

Comment: I suppose I can take it out.

Comment: I would get rid of that.  The only thing that could force it to change the SelectedIndex is adding/removing items from it or otherwise binding it to a new data source.

Comment: Well it certainly helps. Now it is only having problems when a particular button is clicked. Its better. I will have to spend some more time investigating it.